# Item (Mage_Admin_Model_Block) with the same id "0" already exist

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions

When I am trying to add new block permission from `System->Permission->Blocks->Add New Block` .
Can any one tell me that how can I recover from this error.
Magento Version : 1.9.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Solved By Self : 
Goto `permission_block` table from the database.and than set "auto increment" `block_id`.